# Magento2 Delta migration Deltalog for catalog_product_super_attribute_pricing is not installed In Delta.php line 129

Tags: magento2

I am running this command

```
php bin/magento migrate:delta -r -a /home/quaid/Hairbodyskin_Project/freshhbsm2/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.2.1/config.xml
```

and I face this error

```
Deltalog for catalog_product_super_attribute_pricing is not installed In Delta.php line 129:
                       
Delta delivering failed
```

here is my config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xs:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_DataMigrationTool:etc/config.xsd">
    <steps mode="settings">
        <step title="Settings Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Settings\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Settings\Data</data>
        </step>
        <step title="Stores Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Stores\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Stores\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Stores\Volume</volume>
        </step>
    </steps>
    <steps mode="data">
        <step title="Data Integrity Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\DataIntegrity\Integrity</integrity>
        </step>
        <step title="EAV Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Eav\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Eav\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Eav\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Customer Attributes Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Customer\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Customer\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Customer\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Map Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Map\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Map\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Map\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Url Rewrite Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Log Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Log\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Log\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Log\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Ratings Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Ratings\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Ratings\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Ratings\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="ConfigurablePrices step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="OrderGrids Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Tier Price Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="SalesIncrement Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Inventory Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Inventory\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Inventory\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Inventory\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="PostProcessing Step">
            <data>Migration\Step\PostProcessing\Data</data>
        </step>
    </steps>
    <steps mode="delta">
        <step title="Customer Attributes Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\Customer\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Customer\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Map Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\Map\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Map\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Log Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\Log\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Log\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="ConfigurablePrices step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Tier Price Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Url Rewrite Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="OrderGrids Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="SalesIncrement Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Inventory Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\Inventory\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Inventory\Volume</volume>
        </step>
    </steps>
    <source>
        <database host="127.0.0.1" name="hairbodyskin" user="root" password="tiger" />
    </source>
    <destination>
        <database host="127.0.0.1" name="freshhbsm2local_Data" user="root" password="tiger" />
    </destination>
    <options>
        <map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.2.1/map.xml.dist</map_file>
        <eav_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-eav.xml.dist</eav_map_file>
        <eav_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/eav-document-groups.xml.dist</eav_document_groups_file>
        <eav_attribute_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/eav-attribute-groups.xml.dist</eav_attribute_groups_file>
        <log_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-log.xml.dist</log_map_file>
        <log_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/log-document-groups.xml.dist</log_document_groups_file>
        <settings_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/settings.xml.dist</settings_map_file>
        <customer_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-customer.xml.dist</customer_map_file>
        <customer_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/customer-document-groups.xml.dist</customer_document_groups_file>
        <customer_attribute_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/customer-attribute-groups.xml.dist</customer_attribute_groups_file>
        <delta_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/deltalog.xml.dist</delta_document_groups_file>
        <order_grids_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/order-grids-document-groups.xml.dist</order_grids_document_groups_file>
        <map_document_groups>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-document-groups.xml.dist</map_document_groups>
        <class_map>etc/opensource-to-opensource/class-map.xml.dist</class_map>
        <tier_price_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-tier-price.xml.dist</tier_price_map_file>
        <stores_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-stores.xml.dist</stores_map_file>
        <!--
        In case bulk_size=0 it will be auto-detected for every document.
        -->
        <bulk_size>0</bulk_size>
        <!--
        Set direct_document_copy = 1 for better performance.
        NOTE: 'source' and 'destination' databases MUST be placed on the same MySQL instance
        and 'destination' user MUST be granted with 'SELECT' permissions on 'source' database
         -->
        <direct_document_copy>0</direct_document_copy>
        <source_prefix>ljq_</source_prefix>
        <dest_prefix />
        <auto_resolve_urlrewrite_duplicates>0</auto_resolve_urlrewrite_duplicates>
        <log_file>migration.log</log_file>
        <progress_bar_format>%percent%% [%bar%] Remaining Time: %remaining%</progress_bar_format>
        <upgrade_customer_password_hash>1</upgrade_customer_password_hash>
        <edition_migrate>opensource-to-opensource</edition_migrate>
        <edition_number>1.9.2.1</edition_number>
        <init_statements_source>SET NAMES utf8;</init_statements_source>
        <init_statements_destination>SET NAMES utf8;</init_statements_destination>
        <crypt_key>1ugevi0ny41wruvm1auqn8rrr6gkm7hb</crypt_key>
    </options>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1):

- The problem can be caused by not importing the new data into the
  source database used for the first migration.
- In fact, even when migrating the data delta, it is critical that the
  source database remains the same because the tables detailing the
  migration's status are generated in it.
- Magento uses these tables for each migration performed on the same
  source database, whether it is the first or delta migration.

Try this **config.xml**,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xs:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_DataMigrationTool:etc/config.xsd">
    <steps mode="settings">
        <step title="Settings Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Settings\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Settings\Data</data>
        </step>
        <step title="Stores Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Stores\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Stores\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Stores\Volume</volume>
        </step>
    </steps>
    <steps mode="data">
        <step title="Data Integrity Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\DataIntegrity\Integrity</integrity>
        </step>
        <step title="EAV Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Eav\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Eav\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Eav\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Customer Attributes Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Customer\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Customer\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Customer\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Map Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Map\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Map\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Map\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Url Rewrite Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Log Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Log\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Log\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Log\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Ratings Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Ratings\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Ratings\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Ratings\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="ConfigurablePrices step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="OrderGrids Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Tier Price Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="SalesIncrement Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Inventory Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Inventory\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Inventory\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Inventory\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="PostProcessing Step">
            <data>Migration\Step\PostProcessing\Data</data>
        </step>
    </steps>
    <steps mode="delta">
        <step title="Customer Attributes Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\Customer\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Customer\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Map Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\Map\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Map\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Log Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\Log\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Log\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="ConfigurablePrices step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Tier Price Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Url Rewrite Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="OrderGrids Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="SalesIncrement Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Inventory Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\Inventory\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Inventory\Volume</volume>
        </step>
    </steps>
    <source>
        <database host="127.0.0.1" name="hairbodyskin" user="root" password="tiger" />
    </source>
    <destination>
        <database host="127.0.0.1" name="freshhbsm2local_Data" user="root" password="tiger" />
    </destination>
    <options>
        <map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.2.1/map.xml.dist</map_file>
        <eav_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-eav.xml.dist</eav_map_file>
        <eav_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/eav-document-groups.xml.dist</eav_document_groups_file>
        <eav_attribute_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/eav-attribute-groups.xml.dist</eav_attribute_groups_file>
        <log_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-log.xml.dist</log_map_file>
        <log_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/log-document-groups.xml.dist</log_document_groups_file>
        <settings_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/settings.xml.dist</settings_map_file>
        <customer_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-customer.xml.dist</customer_map_file>
        <customer_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/customer-document-groups.xml.dist</customer_document_groups_file>
        <customer_attribute_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/customer-attribute-groups.xml.dist</customer_attribute_groups_file>
        <delta_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/deltalog.xml.dist</delta_document_groups_file>
        <order_grids_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/order-grids-document-groups.xml.dist</order_grids_document_groups_file>
        <map_document_groups>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-document-groups.xml.dist</map_document_groups>
        <class_map>etc/opensource-to-opensource/class-map.xml.dist</class_map>
        <tier_price_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-tier-price.xml.dist</tier_price_map_file>
        <stores_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-stores.xml.dist</stores_map_file>
        <!--
        In case bulk_size=0 it will be auto-detected for every document.
        -->
        <bulk_size>0</bulk_size>
        <!--
        Set direct_document_copy = 1 for better performance.
        NOTE: 'source' and 'destination' databases MUST be placed on the same MySQL instance
        and 'destination' user MUST be granted with 'SELECT' permissions on 'source' database
         -->
        <direct_document_copy>0</direct_document_copy>
        <source_prefix>ljq_</source_prefix>
        <dest_prefix />
        <auto_resolve_urlrewrite_duplicates>0</auto_resolve_urlrewrite_duplicates>
        <log_file>migration.log</log_file>
        <progress_bar_format>%percent%% [%bar%] Remaining Time: %remaining%</progress_bar_format>
        <upgrade_customer_password_hash>1</upgrade_customer_password_hash>
        <edition_migrate>opensource-to-opensource</edition_migrate>
        <edition_number>1.9.2.1</edition_number>
        <init_statements_source>SET NAMES utf8;</init_statements_source>
        <init_statements_destination>SET NAMES utf8;</init_statements_destination>
        <crypt_key>1ugevi0ny41wruvm1auqn8rrr6gkm7hb</crypt_key>
    </options>
</config>
```